# maven release plugin: how to skip releasing of submodule

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-release-plugin

I have a multi-module project with one git-submodule, following structure

```
<modules>
   <module>common</module>
   <module>first</module>
   <module>second</module
</modules>
```

Module `common` is a git-submodule.
During the release process, module `common` should not be released - meaning its version shall not change and it pom.xml shouldn't be modified. Other modules shall be released.
I've tried a lot of configuration of maven release:prepare plugin but nothing works.

The only option which works is to pass `-pl common` to maven command line - but the problem is that this code is build by gitlab which is using common release procedure and it's not easy to pass it.

How can I "tell" the maven release plugin to simply ignore this module? Or maybe there's a possibility to pass command line argument `-pl common` via pom.xml?

Thanks

Comment: Why should those modules not being released as you made them part of your multi module structure? If those versions of those modules shouldn't be modified that why have you made them part of a multi module structure (the same version and the same time to release them is one of the foundation ideas behind that)...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this plugin **multi-module-maven-release-plugin**:

> A module is only released if there are changes to it !

Add the following to your plugins section:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.danielflower.mavenplugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>multi-module-maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.4</version>
</plugin>
```

Release your project by running `mvn releaser:release`